# Rich notification with Twilio notify

Tags: twilio

I am using twilio to bulk notify (push) customers when we have outages etc, and that works well at the moment. However we are looking to embed some images in certain notifications.
Just wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach media for SMS (MMS). I have never seen a push directly include media.

```
notification = service.notifications
  .create({
    toBinding: bindings,
    sms: {
      body: body,
      media_urls: [
        "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get.php?api_key=MTAx&id=da1"
      ]
    }
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(notification);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```